# I can't seem to gain control of the Style of a particular element

Tags: html, css

There's an image that I want to position absolute and add a z-index too, but I can't seem to effect it.

```
 <div>  
   <ul class="etalage">
     <li>
       <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="codecanyon/demo_files/images/image1_thumb.jpg">
       <img class="etalage_source_image" src="codecanyon/demo_files/images/image1_large.jpg">
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I can control the over style using:

```
.etalage {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
```

But this doesn't effect the source image I want it to:

```
.etalage_source_image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  left: 140px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? :_\

Comment: try giving poistion:relative to your parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should style the position of the wrapper as relative, a page element with relative positioning gives you the control to absolutely position children elements inside of it.

```
.etalage {
    position: relative:
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.etalage {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;
  position:relative;
}

.etalage_source_image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  left: 140px;
  width: xx;
  height: xx;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

I think  instead of giving `position:relative` to `ul`,you should give to your parent div